# как прослушивать переменную и при изменениях перестраивать streamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

я пытаюсь сделать календарь с событиями. когда нажимаешь на какой то день в firebase передается дата, после чего я в listView builder делаю лист событий, но когда я нажимаю на другую дата ничего не меняется так как в stream у меня указана база данных.
в переменную thisday передается строка с месяцем и днем (например '04 22') после нажатия на дату в календаре.
то есть при изменении в thisday я должен менять события.

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream:
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(thisDay).snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['img']),
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['name'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                  .data()['subtittle']),
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                },
```

Comment: `StreamBuilder` подписывается на определенный `stream`, а при смене даты вы делаете замену `stream`. Т.е. вы не должны заменять `stream`, вы должны добавлять в уже подписанный `stream` изменения.

Comment: как мне это сделать ?

Comment: создать новый `stream` через `async*` и отправлять в него данные из других `stream'ов`